# xcode read/writing file not found

Tags: c, xcode, file-io

When i test this code out i cannot locate my "myFile". I tried searching for it in spotlight but it doesn't find anything. If i use the exact same code in codeblocks then i am able to see "myFile". Are there any other steps i need to make to create the file in xcode?

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
{
FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("myFile.txt","w");
    fprintf(fp,"%s\n","Hi");
    fprintf(fp,"%s\n","Yes");
    fprintf(fp,"%d\n",234);
    fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

UPDATE

For anyone out there wondering the same question the answer is go to Preference > location > advance> custom > choose relative to workspace. That solved my issue.

Comment: Looks ok, as long as you have write access to the place where you want to create or open the file.  Try checking the return value, `fp` - if it is NULL, then check `errno` to see what error occurred.

Comment: Assuming it is run in a directory where you can write, the code should be fine and should create the file.  Permissions are unlikely to be the problem.  That leaves the problem of "why can't you find the file?"  Have you tried using `find` in a terminal window?  `find $HOME -name myFile.txt` for example.

Comment: i checked for NULL and it didnt print error.. i just cant locate the file...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler just tried it still nothing.. very strange..

Comment: Have you tried checking that `fopen()` succeeds.  Have you tried printing messages to standard output too?  Do you see them?  I work on a Mac but don't use XCode UI because I'm too lazy to learn it.  I've not yet found a UI that doesn't drive me bonkers (Eclipse, …).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler fopen() doesn't open anything.. so it seems like it hasn't created the file..

Comment: Correct.  So now you need to find out why the file was not created. Use `perror()` (crude but simple) to see why not.  You may need to use `getcwd()` to get the current directory and print that.  And maybe `sleep(10)` before exiting.